# For loop iterator issues c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iterator, try-catch

I having a problem getting my code to throw runtime errors as well getting these loops to work properly, and I'm not sure why.

If the user were to enter a name and balance, for example: josh 100, the program should add 100 to the account named josh in listAccounts vector, and then print the new balance.

something about the line: for ( ; iter !=  listAccounts.end(); iter++) {

For some reason it's causing the if statements to not work, if I comment out that line the function works but only with the last element in listAccounts. Is something wrong with the for loop that is causing it to not step through each element?

```
void Account::change_balance(string name, int balance, int i) {
    try {
        auto iter = listAccounts.begin();

        for ( ; iter !=  listAccounts.end(); iter++) {

            if ((*iter).account_name == name) {
                if (((*iter).account_type == 0) && (((*iter).account_balance + 
                balance) < 0)) {
                    throw runtime_error("account cannot hold negative 
                    balance");                    
                    (*iter).account_balance = (((*iter).account_balance) -
                    (balance));
                    cout << (*iter).account_balance;                                                
                } else {                                                                            
                    (*iter).account_balance = balance + 
                    (*iter).account_balance;
                    cout << (*iter).account_balance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (runtime_error& e) {         
        cout << "error on line " << i << ": " << e.what() << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where I have gone wrong, any indication would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your inner for-loop. You never increase the iterator, all you do is comparing listAccounts.size() times the same element of the vector with the function argument. As the loops ends when k == listAccounts.size(), the condition n == listAccounts.size() can only be fulfilled when the outer loop goes for at least another run, because you did not clear n (or defined it locally). But now, it may fire and say "Account not found" even though it is there, because n == listAccounts.size(). This is not the behaviour your intended.

You should rethink your algorithm. Why do you traverse all the accounts each time you traverse the list of accounts? It would be totally sufficient to do it once. Consider doing something like this:

```
for(auto& account : listAccounts) {
   if(account.account_name == name) {
      // do your logic stuff and eventually:
      return;
   }
}
// if your program gets here, no account with such a name was found
```

Comment: I see, thanks. But that doesn't explain why it's not throwing the error when an attempt is made to make the account_balance of type = 0, less than 0. And as to why it is not updating the vector element when a correct balance is input.

Comment: Yes, it does explain it. As I already told you, those part of the code actually never get reached because of your errorneous inner loop implementation. Why bother about an algorithm that cannot work anyway?